# JDBC timeout is not throwing SQLTimeoutException

Tags: jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am trying to set the query timeout on a JDBC Statement and expecting it to throw an SQLTimeoutException when it times out.
But instead I am getting a generic SQLException with error code ORA-01013.

Any idea what I must be missing?

I am looking for a DB independent way to handle timeouts. And checking for DB specific error codes may not help there.

BTW, I am setting this property via Spring's JdbcTemplate.

```java
myStatement.setQueryTimeout(1);
```

throws

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation
```

Edit: Here is the stack trace for the error. I am using a thin driver (ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar).

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:205)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:861)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1145)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1259)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3493)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:703)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:722)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:772)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:211)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:219)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:233)
    at mytest.MyDAO.retrieve(MyDAO.java:12)
```

Comment: Evidence? Stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is code used by driver to throw exception/error and it does not do anything to map exception to SQLTimeoutException. This is gap in oracle driver implementation

refer 
https://github.com/wenshao/OracleDriver10_2_0_2/blob/4af5a9295e0e9fef3f7e51ba7bf735fb81e9186a/src/oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CTTIoer.java

the snippet taken from below full method is

```
     DatabaseError.throwSqlException(this.meg.conv
                    .CharBytesToString(this.errorMsg, this.errorLength[0],
                            true), DatabaseError
                    .ErrorToSQLState(this.retCode), this.retCode);
```

The full method is this

```
/*     */
/*     */void processError(boolean paramBoolean,
        OracleStatement paramOracleStatement)
/*     */throws SQLException
/*     */{
    /* 303 */if (this.retCode != 0)
    /*     */{
        /* 311 */switch (this.retCode)
        /*     */{
        /*     */case 28:
            /*     */
        case 600:
            /*     */
        case 1012:
            /*     */
        case 3113:
            /*     */
        case 3114:
            /* 323 */this.connection.internalClose();
            /*     */}
        /*     */
        /* 328 */if (paramBoolean)
        /*     */{
            **/* 331 */
             *DatabaseError.throwSqlException(this.meg.conv
                    .CharBytesToString(this.errorMsg, this.errorLength[0],
                            true), DatabaseError
                    .ErrorToSQLState(this.retCode), this.retCode);*
            /*     */}
        /*     */else
        /*     */{
            /* 335 */return;
            /*     */}
        /*     */
        /*     */}
    /*     */
    /* 341 */if (!paramBoolean) {
        /* 342 */return;
        /*     */}
    /*     */
    /* 351 */if ((this.warningFlag & 0x1) == 1)
    /*     */{
        /* 353 */int i = this.warningFlag & 0xFFFFFFFE;
        /*     */
        /* 356 */if (((i & 0x20) == 32) || ((i & 0x4) == 4)) {
            /* 357 */throw DatabaseError.newSqlException(110);
            /*     */}
        /*     */}
    /*     */
    /* 361 */if ((this.connection != null)
            && (this.connection.plsqlCompilerWarnings))
    /*     */{
        /* 363 */if ((this.flags & 0x4) == 4)
            /* 364 */paramOracleStatement.foundPlsqlCompilerWarning();
        /*     */}
    /*     */}
```

Comment: Thank you sandeep. I guess then I have to resort to the dirty way of making error code checks myself.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately JDBC drivers do not always implement everything required (or: suggested) by JDBC. The especially applies to 'newer' features. `SQLTimeoutException` was added in Java 6 / JDBC 4.

This has two implications:

1. It isn't available in older versions,
2. You need a driver that is for JDBC 4 or higher.

There are also further complications:

1. Given the specific error message (*"ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation"*) in your question, it might simply be impossible for the driver to discern an actual user initiated cancellation of the statement from one initiated by a timeout. In that case it is better to throw the most generic exception type.
2. If a vendor supports multiple Java and JDBC versions, they might simply be taking shortcuts and only do the minimum to be (almost) JDBC-compliant. This might include only throwing `SQLException` to make it easier for them to use the same code-base with a minimum of fuss.